# Requiring unknown module "react-native-fbsdklogin"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fbsdkloginkit

Tried to include [react-native-fbsdklogin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbsdklogin) in my React-native project with no success.

[image: error]

It looks like it has been added to my project...?

[image: frameworkinproject]

And it is also added to the header search paths...?

[image: headerpaths]

I followed the manual installation steps from the npm module page. I used the `rnpm link` command to automatically link it in my project. I restarted the packager and did a `project >> clean`. The project builds successfully, but everything I try isn't clearing this error.

What is wrong here and how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by referencing the relative path to the module:

`import FBSDKLogin, {FBSDKLoginButton, FBSDKLoginManager} from '../../../node_modules/react-native-fbsdklogin/FBSDKLogin.ios';`